# QWebEngineView открытие в дефолтном браузере

Tags: c++, qt

Используется acceptNavigationRequest, при нажатии на ссылку, открывается дефолтный браузер и открывает ссылку. Хотя я устанавливаю QWebEnginePage:

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H
#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QWebEnginePage>
#include <QDesktopServices>
namespace Ui {
class view;
}
class MyQWebEnginePage : public QWebEnginePage
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyQWebEnginePage(QObject* parent = 0) : QWebEnginePage(parent){}

    bool acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl & url, QWebEnginePage::NavigationType type, bool)
    {
        qDebug() << "acceptNavigationRequest("<<url << "," << type << "," << ")";
        if (type == QWebEnginePage::NavigationTypeLinkClicked)
        {
            QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
class view : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit view(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~view();

private:
    Ui::view *ui;
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    QWebEngineView *viewer = new QWebEngineView(this);
    MyQWebEnginePage *page = new MyQWebEnginePage();
private slots:
};

#endif // VIEW_H
```

cpp

```
#include "view.h"
#include "ui_view.h"
view::view(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::view)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
    layout->addWidget(viewer);
    viewer->setPage(page);
    viewer->load(QUrl("http://videoa.npointerro.ru"));
   // viewer->load(QUrl("http://google.com/"));

}

view::~view()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Вопрос в чем? Вы своими руками открывается браузер по умолчанию

Comment: @ixSci а как тогда сделать это?

Comment: Что сделать? В чём Ваш вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если заменить `QDesktopServices::openUrl(url);` на `setUrl(url)`, ссылка откроется в том же `MyQWebEnginePag`e. Я угадал, это то, что Вам нужно?